# QMChatViewController resulting in "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I have an application which uses QuickBlox as a chat service. Everything I have builds including various QuickBlox services and session libraries. However, when I try to use QMChatViewController by simply importing it anywhere:

```
import QMChatViewController
```

these errors appear:

```
self.imagePhoto.imageURL = NSURL(string: url)
"Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable"
```

and

```
imageView.imageURL = NSURL(string: photoURL)
"Cannot assign to property: 'imageView' is a 'let' constant"
```

I think it has something to do with AsyncImageView but I've removed the pod and it's still happening. When the 'import QMChatViewController' line is removed, the project builds fine. Anyone familiar with 'self is immutable' build errors?

Comment: Found the reason. QMChatViewController comes with SDWebImage which has an extension for UIImageView with imageURL(). This makes any previous calls to asyncImageView.imageURL = ... to have that error. Answer below seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a value to an immutable object by using "setValue"

```
self.imageView.setValue(NSURL(string: photoURL), forKey: "imageURL")
```

Comment: This is the solution that I've gone with and it works to set the imageView property on AsyncImageView.